# NameError: name 'First_Nam' is not defined

Tags: subclass, instance-variables, nameerror

**Bank Program**

I have made a class Account with it's own attributes, one of which is First_Nam. Then, in my main() function I assign the value of an input object to an **instance** of the class Account.
I also have a child class of the Account class called Bank.

Everytime I run my program I get this error message:NameError: name 'First_Nam' is not defined.

````
    
    def __init__(self, Account_Number, First_Nam, Last_Nam, SSN, PIN, Bal):
        self.Account_Number = Account_Number
        self.First_Nam = First_Nam
        self.Last_Nam = Last_Nam
        self.SSN = SSN
        self.PIN = PIN
        self.Bal = Bal  

class Bank(Account):
        
#At least 2 test units must be written for EACH method!
    def __init__(self, Account_Number, PIN, Bal):
        super().__init__(self, Account_Number, First_Nam, Last_Nam, SSN, PIN, Bal) 
        self.Account_Number
        self.PIN
        self.Bal
def main():
    First = input("Please enter your first name: ")
    Last = input("Please enter your last name: ")
    SSN = input("Please enter your SSN: ")
    a = random.choices((0,9), k =8)
    p = random.choices((0,9), k =4)
    Bal = 0.00
    client_account = Account(a, First, Last, SSN, p, Bal)```

Any advice would be great guys!
````